# How to send variable value from one function to other function in a different page

Tags: php, oop, frameworks

I'm new to php oop and I wanted to send the variable value from one function to another in a different page. So, currently I have this one function in one page that I want to send the data to the other function in a different page. Is that even possible perhaps?

Here's the first function in sendData.php

```
public function main($data) {

    $settings = new Settings();

    $hash_code = md5('standard' . '10068' . '08f94110d5697a2497511594c31704d0' .'3.00');
    $std_post = array(
                        'apitype'=>'standard',              //fix value
                        'apiid'=>'10068',               //your api id from ibill
                        'apiorderid'=>'OPC0001#00000282',               //your order id
                        'apihashcode'=>$hash_code,          //generate hash code as above
                        'apiamount'=>'3.00',                //your customer transaction amount
                        'apiemail'=>'alif4arsenal97@gmail.com');        //your customer email

   $callbackJSON = json_encode($std_post);

    $url = 'https://ibill.my/merchant/?ng=callback_api';        //link need to send data
    $ch = curl_init($url);                                      // where to post                                                                   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $callbackJSON);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    $headers   = array();
    $headers[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
      echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    //echo $results;

    $objJSON = json_decode($results);                       //decode json result

    //should return 'SUCCESS'
    $callback_status = $objJSON->{'callback_status'};       //callback Status
    $message = $objJSON->{'message'};                       //callback Message 

    //Refer on statuspage.php
    $std_status_code = $objJSON->{'std_status_code'};       //payment status code
    $std_status = $objJSON->{'std_status'};                 //payment status
    $std_order_id = $objJSON->{'std_order_id'};             //your order id
    $std_purchase_code = $objJSON->{'std_purchase_code'};   //ibill transaction id
    $std_amount = $objJSON->{'std_amount'};                 //transaction amount
    $std_datepaid = $objJSON->{'std_datepaid'};             //transaction date time

    //Hash code for security
    $std_hash_code = $objJSON->{'std_hash_code'};           //Hash code
    $hash_code = md5('08f94110d5697a2497511594c31704d0'.'10068'.$std_order_id.$std_amount); //hash code format

    $data = [
        'callback_status' => $callback_status,
        'message' => $message,
        'std_status_code' => $std_status_code,
        'std_status' => $std_status,
        'std_order_id' => $std_order_id,
        'std_purchase_code' => $std_purchase_code,
        'std_amount' => $std_amount,
        'std_datepaid' => $std_datepaid,
        'std_hash_code' => $std_hash_code,
        'hash_code' => $hash_code 
    ];

    processPayment($data);

}
```

Here's the second function in a different that I wanted the data in the first page to be send to which is test.php

```
public function processPayment($data)
{
    if (!isset($data['std_status_code'])) return false;
    if (!isset($data['std_hash_code'])) return false;

    $settings = new Settings();

    $sale_id = (int) substr($data['std_order_id'], 8);

    $sale = Sales::get($sale_id);

    if (empty($sale)) return false;

    if ($sale['status'] == 1) return $sale;

    if ($sale['payment_method'] !== 'ibill' || $sale['status'] != 0) return false;

    $sale_uid = $sale['uid'];
    $sale_method = $sale['method'];

    $paid_amount = bcadd($sale['total_amount'], $sale['handling_charge'], 2);

    // Verify the data integrity sent by iBill
    $hash = md5($settings->ibill_secret_key . $settings->ibill_merchant_id . $data['std_order_id'] . $data['std_amount']);

    $payment_processor_status = -1;
    $sale_status = 0;

    // Check provided hash and status
    if ($hash === $data['std_hash_code'] && $data['std_status_code'] == 00) {
        $payment_processor_status = 1;
        $sale_status = 1;
    }

    if ($sale_status === 0) {
        if ($data['std_status_code'] != 00) {
            $data['std_status'] = '<span style="color: red">' . $data['std_status'] . '</span>';
        }

        if ($data['std_hash_code'] !== $hash) {
            $data['std_hash_code'] = '<span style="color: red">' . $data['std_hash_code'] . '</span>';
        }
    }

    // Prepare updated sale data
    $now = new DateTime();

    $sale = [
        'payment_processor_status' => $payment_processor_status,
        'payment_processor_data' => $data,
        'payment_time' => $now->format('g:i:s A'),
        'payment_date' => $now->format('d-m-Y')
    ];

    Sales::update($sale_id, $sale);

    if ($sale_status === 1) {
        Sales::confirmSale($sale_id, false);
    }

    return ['uid' => $sale_uid, 'method' => $sale_method];
}
```

Comment: Use php sessions

Comment: Those looks like class methods, not functions. To call a class method, you need to create an instance of the class and call the method on that. As long as both files are either included in your script or if you have an auto loader set up, it shouldn't be an issue. However, when calling a class method, you need to instantiate the class `$foo = new Foo();` and then `$foo->someMethod();`, not just `someMethod();`.

Comment: I see, so this is class method. So, to send the data what should i be doing in sendData.php and test.php? i still dont understand on what you just explained just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions are class methods, not only functions.
you can use them (or pass data from one to another) by creating instances of their classes. for example something like this:

```
class one {
    public function f1($data) {
        // do something
        $instance = new two();
        $instance->f2($data);
    }
}

class two {
    public function f2($data) {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

I hope it would work for you.